# Data Security - Encryption

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

What are the possible ways to make data meaning less through encryption or some techniques but without compromising performance.

As per my knowledge column based encryption has a cost of performance.

We need some better way to hide data from unauthorized access and make it meaningless if someone got direct access to it.

Note: Mostly we have Standard edition ( 20 server with mixture of 2008 to 2014) but also

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 - 10.50.6000.34 (X64) 
    Aug 19 2014 12:21:34 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit)

Comment: could you provide your sql server version and edition , whether you are looking to do this through your code or using what's available with MSSQL.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? Meet some requirement that says you have encrypted your data (checkbox) or do you have specific threats you want to protect your data from? Do you need to protect it on disk or inflight or both? Do you need to block DBAs also? More details will help us guide you to a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

For your Enterprise edition instance(s) I would recommend you look into Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) [MSSQL TDE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049(v=sql.110).aspx)

for your Standrd Edition Instance you would have to look into encryption options of .net or OS level encryption options such as Bitlocker

hope this info helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

[This article from MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098(v=sql.100).aspx) describes the encryption options available in SQL 2008 r2.

[This article at SQL Matters](http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Pros%20and%20Cons%20of%20Transparent%20Data%20Encryption%20(TDE).aspx) provides some pros and cons you should note.

Note that TDE encrypts data "at rest" or in the data files. It does *not* encrypt data "on the move" or between the database and your application. For that, [you need to use SSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067.aspx).

There will be some degree of performance impact, but you'll need to measure that to see whether it is noticeable.